# Why does some templated code fail to compile with MinGW-64 gcc version 11.2.0?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, c++17, c++20

Specifically it is (an excerpt from https://github.com/dillonhuff/gpr), which fails to compile on line with `parse_stream` constructor definition:

```
#include "parser.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <streambuf>

using namespace std;

namespace gpr {
  
  template<typename T>
  struct parse_stream {
    size_t i;
    vector<T> s;

    template<typename R>
    parse_stream<T>(R v) : s(v.begin(), v.end()) { // COMPILE ERROR: expected ')' before 'v'
      i = 0;
    }
(...)
}
```

and parser.h just contains this:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#include "gcode_program.h"

namespace gpr {

  std::vector<std::string> lex_block(const std::string& block_text);

  gcode_program parse_gcode(const std::string& program_text);

  gcode_program parse_gcode_saving_block_text(const std::string& program_text);

}
```

This used to compile just fine with MSVC 2019, and just "a while ago" with lower MinGW-64 gcc version. It seems to have something to do with C++ standard (17 vs 20), as lowering the C++ version settings in the Qt .pro file seems to fix it (but then I loose .contains() from std::map and couple of other features).

Maybe I am blind, but I just don't see, what is wrong here! Please help.

EDIT: Adding an exact compiler error

```
../gpr/src/parser.cpp:19:22: error: expected ')' before 'v'
   19 |     parse_stream<T>(R v) : s(v.begin(), v.end()) {
      |                    ~ ^~
      |                      )
```

EDIT: NathanOliver's comment helps to resolve the compilation. It compiles with (without the `T` parameter declaration):

```
template<typename R>
    parse_stream(R v) : s(v.begin(), v.end()) { // NOW OK!
      i = 0;
    }
```

(Not sure if it is a fix or a workaround to a compiler bug, as the main question remains unanswered.)

Comment: Can you show us the exact error message, and make a [mcve]?

Comment: Added an EDIT with the compiler error - nothing new, exactly the same thing as the comment in the code. The minimal example may take a little more time.

Comment: Does it go away if you change `parse_stream<T>(R v)` to `parse_stream(R v)`?

Comment: Yes @NathanOliver, it does! Many thanks :) Can You tell me what was the problem? Did anything change in the standard? Why it did compile and now - not?

Comment: C++20 shipped a lot of changes to templates, and this must be one of those things.  I haven't familiarized myself with all of the changes yet to know if this is an actual change or a bug, but I'm leaning towards a change to the language.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thank You. Would You like to post an answer/fix or You would like me to do it?/ Or don't mind :)

Comment: @forestgril I'm holding off on answering because I can't answer the question of why this change is needed.  If you want to leave your own answer showing how you solved it, go ahead.  If I can figure out what changed, I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: Great, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Why is there no initializer for i in the list initializer?
It should read like this:

```
template <class R> explicit parse_stream(R v) : i{}, v{ std::vector<T>(v.begin(), v.end()) } {}
```

EDIT: It might make sense to provide an overload for the case where `R` is of `decltype (v)`, namely a `std::vector<T>`, in which case we could just move the whole thing. Like this:

```
explicit parse_stream(std::vector<T> v) : i{}, v{ std::move(v) } {}
```

Comment: While being good practice, this is not required nor should it be the cause/fix the compiler error the OP is getting

Comment: Upvoting for good practices. Thanks!

Comment: I know. In this case it changes nothing. There are so many cases where it does, many of which being "Ill formed, no diagnosis required" that it would be ill-advised for me not to point it out considering it might be an oversight. (I'll politely assume it is)